# How do angles work in 3D rotation?

Tags: css, rotation, transform

As you know, for 3D transformations you need methods like **rotateX(20deg)** I know how to use both 2D and 3D transforms but what I can't understand is how angles work. I mean, if I have to rotate a div along X axis in **clockwise direction** (I don't even know if saying clockwise/anti-clockwise is right or wrong), I don't know whether to use +ve angle or -ve angle, until I try them individually to get the desired rotation.

Check the following example.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
div[id^="d"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
#d1 {
  background: red;
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(70deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}
#d2 {
  background: blue;
  left: 600px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-70deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#d3 {
  background: purple;
  top: 200px;
  left: 800px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-70deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
#d4 {
  background: grey;
  top: 200px;
  left: 600px;
}
#d5 {
  background: lightgreen;
  top: 400px;
  left: 600px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(70deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}
#d6 {
  background: orange;
  top: 200px;
  left: 600px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="d1">d1</div>
    <div id="d2">d2</div>
    <div id="d3">d3</div>
    <div id="d4">d4</div>
    <div id="d5">d5</div>
    <div id="d6">d6</div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to make a cube. I'm sure I'll make it without any problem, anyhow. But if you see, **d3** and **d5** both have clockwise rotations (according to me), **but one has +ve angle and other has -ve angle!**

I don't understand this. How do I understand it?

Answer (score 3):

In [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/) you can read:

> **rotate() = `rotate( <angle> )`**
>   specifies a 2D rotation by the angle
>   specified in the parameter about the origin of the element, as defined
>   by the transform-origin property. For example, rotate(90deg) would
>   cause elements to appear rotated one-quarter of a turn in the
>   clockwise direction.
>   [[w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#funcdef-rotate)]

So a positive value means the element is rotated in the clockwise direction. Example:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:2px solid;
  text-align:center;
  margin:50px;
}
.plus{
  transform:rotate(30deg);
}
.min{
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="plus">positive</div>
<div class="min">negative</div>
```

If you need to define the rotation direction before you test it, you have to imagine the 3d [XYZ] coordinate system:

[image: 3D coordinate system for CSS transforms]

The clockwise and anti-clockwise directions work **when the arrow is pointing towards you**. For your specific example with the 3d cube, you will see that `#d3` and `#d5` aren't rotating in the same direction. `#d5` is rotating clockwise but `#d3` isn't. If you "look up to it" with the Y axis arrow pointing towards you can see **it is rotating anti-clockwise**.

Here is another example with a `rotateY()` and `rotateX()` transforms. `rotateX()` is positive (clockwise direction) and `rotateY()` is negative (anti-clockwise direction):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(30deg);
  transition: transform 2s;
}
div:hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-60deg) rotateX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>
```

Comment: I guess that the OP confusion comes from thinking about the  Y axis going *upwards* , while the standard defines it going *downwards*

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why d3 and d5 have different signs despite both rotate clockwise?

Comment: @VikasKumar `d3` doesn't rotate clockwise. The transform-origin it on it's left and if you "look up to it" (so the Y axis is pointing towards you as specified in the answer) you will see it is rotating anti-clockwise.

Comment: Thank you I understand it. As @vals said, I always thought Y axis is taken as upwards.